# Cant we do both storing cookie in SharedPreferences and returning a JSONObject from a AsyncTask class

Tags: android, cookies, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I was trying to store cookie received from server into shared preference and then returning a JSONObject in the overridden doinbackground method of a class extending AsyncTask.

but this shows error at the statement where i check the string in onpostexecute method i.e.

```
if (jsonObject.getString("firstTime").equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
```

but when i remove the the code written to store cookie as a string in sharedPreferences then it works fine i.e.

```
List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

            cook = cookies.toString();

            // to store only the value of cookie i.e 26 character long
            cook = cook.substring(38, 64);
            Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("cookie", result);
            editor.commit();
```

here is the complete code of both method.

```
@Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String cook = "";

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {

                List<BasicNameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
                list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "login"));
                list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", editEmail.getText()
                        .toString()));
                list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", editPassword
                        .getText().toString()));
                // list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cookie", receivedCookie));
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));

                // executing with httpPost and httpContext

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                // checking the CookieStore after logging in

                List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

                cook = cookies.toString();

                // to store only the value of cookie i.e 26 character long
                cook = cook.substring(38, 64);
                Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("cookie", cook);
                editor.commit();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity()
                                .getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                    builder.append(line + "\n");
                }

                jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());

            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // return result;
            return jsonObject;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
            pDialog.dismiss();

            try {
                if (jsonObject.getString("firstTime").equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    textView.setText("checking for the data");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

what is reason behind it and how can achieve both of these without getting error?

Comment: I don't understand this: `editor.putString("cookie", result);`. Shouldn't you be storing the `String cook`?

Comment: corrected it ... but still the result is same.

Comment: Is the app crashing or just printing a `JSONException` to the `LogCat`? Post the logs.

Comment: Got the solution but not the reason. just moved this storing cookie code below `jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an exception occurred when you try to get and save the cookie and that make the `jsonObject` creation statement unreachable and the `jsonObject` will stay null, so when you tried to call `jsonObject.getString("firstTime")` you got an error.

You can solve the problem by reordering your code as the follow

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity()
                            .getContent(), "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
     builder.append(line + "\n");
}

jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());

// checking the CookieStore after logging in
List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
cook = cookies.toString();
// to store only the value of cookie i.e 26 character long
cook = cook.substring(38, 64);
Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("cookie", cook);
editor.commit();
```

Or just check if your cookie is not null before trying to use `substring` method, or you can just put the cookie things on try and catch block as follow

```
try {
    // checking the CookieStore after logging in
    List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    cook = cookies.toString();
    // to store only the value of cookie i.e 26 character long
    cook = cook.substring(38, 64);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("cookie", cook);
    editor.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Cookie Error",e.getMessage());
}
```